# A question about closure in group definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am studying [Group](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Group.html), and have a doubt about `closure`:

> 1. Closure: If A and B are two elements in G, then the product AB is also in G.

I am not a nitpicker, and just want to make sure whether `A` and `B` can be the same element?

Comment: Yes, they can, but standard notation in Group Theory is to use lower case for elements, upper case for the group and any subsets.

Comment: Yes, in fact if $G = \{1\}$ (a trivial group) $A$ and $B$ *have* to be the same element.

Comment: In fact, throughout mathematics, two distinct symbols $a,b$ are allowed to represent the same object, unless either (1) it's explicitly specified that $a,b$ are distinct objects, or (2)  the context makes it clear that the objects must be distinct.